# how to close FlyoutHeader xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin

when I click the red box in android, the FlyoutHeader closes, but in ios it clicks on the item instead of just closing. What I can do?

Xamarin Forms Version 4.6.0.800

**It is not master-detalpage** is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout

thank you very much

[android example Working good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gerB.gif)

[ios example not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPckC.gif)

[red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBhSa.png)

Comment: It should work on iOS out of the box. May be some of your changes might have caused this side effect. You can compare you code with the sample here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/

Comment: Also it is good practice to post a skeleton code along with the question. It helps other to understand the question.